# Extension that creates object from all selected variables

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I am looking for a vscode extension that can take a function like this;

```
const hello = () => {
    const name = () => {}
    const age = () => {}
    const height = () => {}
    const location = () => {}
}
```

And add create an object of all the declare variables in the function:

```
const hello = () => {
    const name = () => {}
    const age = () => {}
    const height = () => {}
    const location = () => {}
    return { name, age, height, location }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a snippet and a keybinding.

In your snippet file:

```
"return object": {
  "prefix": "_ro",
  "body": [
    "$TM_SELECTED_TEXT",

    // "\treturn { ${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/\\s*const\\s+(.*)\\b.*(\\n)*/$1, /g} }", 

    "${TM_CURRENT_LINE/^(\\s*).*$/$1/}return { ${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/\\s*const\\s+(.*)\\b[^\\}]*((\\}\\s)|(\\}))/$1${3:+, }/g} }",

  ],
  "description": "Return Object"
},
```

And some keybinding of your choice:

```
  {
    "key": "alt+b",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
      "name": "return object"
    }
  },
```

The snippet looks hairy but most of it is fine-tuning perhaps you could live without.  The commented code would yield:

`return { name, age, height, location,  }`  // note the extra `,` after the last entry.

I'll explain the full transform:

`"${TM_CURRENT_LINE/^(\\s*).*$/$1/}return { ${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/\\s*const\\s+(.*)\\b[^\\}]*((\\}\\s)|(\\}))/$1${3:+, }/g} }",`

The first part `${TM_CURRENT_LINE/^(\\s*).*$/$1/}` just inserts the same amount of white space you had preceding the last line of the selection for indentation purposes.

This part `${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/\\s*const\\s+(.*)\\b[^\\}]*((\\}\\s)|(\\}))/` gets the variable/function names, your "name", "age", etc. into capture group 1 of the regex.

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/d2GBBu/1)

This part `[^\\}]*((\\}\\s)|(\\}))` at the end of that regex is there to determine if there is another line entry and if so add the `,` to the end of the variable list.   So if there is `}\s` at the end that would go into capture group 3.  If there is only `}` at the end and no other following line in your selection that would be capture group 4 and there would be no capture group 3.

That is important because `${3:+, }` is a conditional transform that says if there is a group 3 - which there won't be for the last entry, because it isn't followed by a newline in the selection - if there is a group 3 add the `,`.  So the full regex transform would yield

`return { name, age, height, location }`

So there is a lot of housekeeping just to get the indentation and commas right, and necessary double-escaping in vscode.  The actual regex is pretty simple.  Here's a demo:

[image: return object with multiple variables]

---

Usage: just be sure to fully select your desired code range - as in the demo - don't partially select the first or last lines for example.

Comment: This is really cool. It's not working for most functions like this: `const userReadById = (id: number) => userFindOne({ id })`.

Comment: Well no, that is a different construct than your example in the question - no `const` for example, which I used in the regex.  I can see if it can be modified for this new use case.  Make the `const` optional...might be enough.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the precise format of this new example and the precise format of your desired result.  Thanks.